# Using Bounded Derivative to Show Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $|f '(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$.
My attempt: I started by observing the definition of uniform continuity, which is for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x,y \in (a,b)$, $|x-y|\lt \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)|\lt \epsilon$. Using this I began by trying to find $\delta$. My first thought was to use the information about the derivative. I wrote out that $\lim_{x\to y}$$|$$(f(x) - f(y) \over x - y)$|$\leq M$. Using this, $-M$($\lim_{x\to y}(x - y))$$\leq$$\lim_{x \to y}(f(x) - f(y))$$\leq$$M(\lim_{x \to y}(x - y))$. Now this implies that $|\lim_{x\to y}f(x) - f(y)|$$\leq$$M(\lim_{x \to y}(x - y))$. I'm thinking that this is what will get me to the $\delta$ that I'm looking for. But the limit on the right hand side approaches 0, so this should imply that $|\lim_{x \to y}f(x) - f(y)|$$\leq$ $0$. Is this the result that will show uniform continuity?

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes I do. Is it possible to partition the interval into smaller intervals and then use the mean value theorem to find $\delta$?

Comment: @Dr.MV No need. Take $a<x<y<b$ and apply the MVT on the interval $[x,y]$

Comment: So using this should I take $\delta$$=$$M|x - y|$?

Comment: @Matt Take $\delta =\epsilon/M$.

Comment: @Dr. MV thank you, I just worked on it for a couple minutes and came across the same result. Just to make sure is this correct. By MVT there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f '(c) = f(x) - f(y)/x - y$. Now |f(x) - f(y)| $\leq$$M|x - y|$$\lt$$M\delta$ = $\epsilon$. Where $\delta$ = $\epsilon$/M

Comment: By the way, note that $f$ is $M$-Lipschitz.

Comment: @Matt  That looks fine.  You might first write that for any closed interval contained on $(a,b)$, we can apply the MVT and ...  ... And then conclude that since $f$ is UC on any closed subset of $(a,b)$ it is UC on $(a,b)$.